# Replace a letter from one array with a letter from another

Tags: c++, qt

How can I replace a letter from one array to the letter from the other? And vice versa. For example `a <-> x, b <-> y, c <-> z`.

Code in C++ , please

```
txtText->setText(txtText->toPlainText().replace(prep[a],QString("x")));
txtText->setText(txtText->toPlainText().replace(prep[b],QString("y")));
txtText->setText(txtText->toPlainText().replace(prep[c],QString("z")));
```

or how? I don't understand

Comment: What "array"? A string?

Comment: 1st array - QString prep[3]={"a","b","c"}

Comment: 2nd - QString prep[3]={"x","y","z"}

Comment: And what exactly do you want to do with them? Update your question rephrased, it's incomprehensible as currently standing.

Comment: For example i have phrase "bad cat". I need to replace the letter so as to obtain like: "yxd zxt"

Comment: This is a cipher. And I do not know how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

`QString::replace` is probably what you need.